# How to make postfix to deliver via a command

Tags: postfix

I have setup a postfix server that will receive several emails and deliver
them to OpenERP.  It's currently working, but I would like to improve the
overall schema so that postfix delivers (i.e Delivered-To) to the OpenERP
email alias.

#### More details about the instalation

The big schema is the following:

1. Installed `postfix-pgsql`.  In my `main.cf` file I have something like:

   ```
   alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
   alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
   myorigin = /etc/mailname
   mydestination = localhost

   virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com
   virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf
   ```
2. The query in `pgsql-aliases.cf`

   ```
   query = SELECT 'oerp@localhost'
           FROM mail_alias a, ir_config_parameter d
           WHERE (d.key = 'mail.catchall.domain')
                 AND (d.value = '%d')
                 AND (a.alias_name = '%u');
   ```
3. Then I have the "oerp" alias in `/etc/aliases`:

   ```
   oerp: "| openerp_mailgate ...args... "
   ```

#### The issue

This setup works fairly well.  Mails are being delivered, etc.  But then, I
have an out-of-my-control MTA (my postfix can relay to that for outsiders)
that relays emails coming to "mydomain.com" to my postfix.

In that MTA there are several rules.  For instance, I you email
to "contact@external-domain.com", the MTA will re-deliver the email
to "contact@mydomain.com" and "boss@external-domain.com".  That redelivery
won't touch original headers.

The "contact@mydomain.com" will handed to my postfix and, ultimately, it will
end up being piped to the mailgate script.  But the "Delivered-To" header will
be changed to "oerp@localhost".

OpenERP looks for the "Delivered-To" header (among others) of the message to
know what to do with it.  But in this case the "Delivered-To" will always be
the same and thus we can't use it for anything important.

I would like to change the schema so that postfix will deliver the email to my
mailgate script without resorting to "oerp@localhost" alias and
the "Delivered-To" remains unchanged (in the example it is expected to
be "contact@mydomain.com").

Any ideas?  I've been playing with the `master.cf` but failed to accomplish
anything.

Comment: I've just came across the `postfix-to-mailmain.py` script that have some very useful tips for my situation.  I will try it and report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Summary of the solution I found:

1. Remove the alias that matches 'oerp@localhost' with the script.
2. Place the script as a pipe in `master.cf`.
3. Create a transport map that matches your OpenERP domain to be delivered to the script previously defined in `master.cf`.
4. Use the `pg_aliases.cf` for a virtual mailbox map instead for alias.  Then remove the oerp alias in `/etc/aliases`.

### Long answer

The previous solution simply gave the same alias for every match resulting in the unreliability of the 'Delivered-To'.  Now what I have done is to recast the entire solution and use a virtual mailbox instead, like:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pg-aliases.cf
```

This take another view to the problem, and IMO is more correct:  Instead giving the same "aliased" mailbox to each message, simply *find a positive* virtual mailbox.

The `pg-aliases.cf` was modified (though this is not strictly need I find it more convenient for logging purposes) to:

```
query = SELECT '%u@%d'
      FROM mail_alias a, ir_config_parameter d
      WHERE (d.key = 'mail.catchall.domain')
            AND (d.value = '%d')
            AND (a.alias_name = '%u');
```

Now you need to define a transport that actually delivers the incoming emails to the mailgate script.  This is done in two steps:

First, configure the mailgate script in the `master.cf` file, like this:

```
openerp   unix  -       n       n       -       1       pipe
   flags=DFR user=openerp argv=/path/to/mailgate.py -d dbname ... etc ..
```

Notice that `1` as the limit.  This is done so that concurrent access to OpenERP server is not possible otherwise messages coming to several `@mydomain.com` address may double in the DB because of transactional isolation.

The write a simple `/etc/postfix/transports` file:

```
mydomain.com  openerp
```

And instruct `main.cf` to read this transport file:

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transports
```

You may forget about the transport map use `virtual_transport=openerp` if the only virtual domain you have is this one.  However, you may find useful to have other internal domains for internal messages, etc.

Comment: Anyway, looks like you have missing `:` character after openerp string in /etc/postfix/transports file

Comment: Is not missing.  See http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html

Comment: Umm, the format of `transport_table` was defined in http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html , especially section **RESULT FORMAT**. Or maybe postfix silently ignored the missing `:` :)

Comment: Ah!  You referred to the result, I misread you thinking about a colon separating the pattern from the result.  The colon seems to be optional when the nexthop is null, though is not documented.  I tested the trailing colon in my workstation and everything kept working.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative solution: You can turn off the `Delivery-To` header when pipe to command by using parameter `prepend_delivered_header`. When delivery-To header was missing, OpenERP will looks into `To` header.

Add this line to `main.cf`

```
prepend_delivered_header = file, forwarding
```

This will disabled `Delivery-To` being added when deliver via command.

The [docs of postfix](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#prepend_delivered_header) said below about `prepend_delivered_header`

> **prepend_delivered_header (default: command, file, forward)**
>
> > The message delivery contexts where the Postfix local(8) delivery agent prepends a Delivered-To: message header with the address that the mail was delivered to. This information is used for mail delivery loop detection.
> >
> > By default, the Postfix local delivery agent prepends a Delivered-To: header when forwarding mail and when delivering to file (mailbox) and command. Turning off the Delivered-To: header when forwarding mail is not recommended.
> >
> > Specify zero or more of forward, file, or command.

Comment: Hi @masegaloeh,  I've actually solve this issue long ago, but at the time I got stuck in other issues, that afterwards I solved as well, so I forgot to answer my own question.

Comment: Hi, would you like to share the solution? You can put it in answer section below and don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yes I will.  It's rather lengthy and since it's for a very specific problem I will point to several specific tools.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of headaches I put together [this solution](https://www.industrialcuriosity.com/2019/08/mail-forwarding-and-piping-emails-with.html) based on a couple of different sources that resulted in much less effort, the critical steps were configuring `virtual_alias_domains` as well as `virtual_alias_maps` and making sure that the virtual mapping was to `my-alias@localhost` instead of just `my-alias`. In my example the command alias is to pipe the email to a website API endpoint, but it could just as easily pipe into something else.

Here are the steps you'll need to take:

- Set up your A and MX records for your domain, the A record @ pointing to the IP of the server you’re going to be receiving emails on and MX with the hostname @ and the value `10 mail.your-domain-name`
- `sudo apt-get install postfix`
- Select "Internet Site" and enter your-domain-name (fully qualified)
- `sudo vi /etc/postfix/main.cf`
- Add mail.your-domain-name to the list of `mydestination` values
- Append

```
virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

to the end of the file

- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/aliases`

```
curl_email: "|curl --data-binary @- http://your-domain-name/email"
```

- `sudo newaliases`
- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/postfix/virtual_domains`

```
example.net   #domain
example.com   #domain
your-domain-name   #domain
```

(the #domain fields suppress warnings)

- `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual_domains`
- `sudo apt-get vi /etc/postfix/virtual`

```
info@your-domain-name bob@gmail.com
everyone@your-domain-name bob@gmail.com jim@gmail.com
email_processor@your-domain-name curl_email@localhost
@your-domain-name catchall@whereveryouwant.com
ted@example.net jane@outlook.com
```

- `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
- `sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload`